# Acess java servlet from an ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have never used ajax and have no idea if I am doing anything right.  I wrote some code to test if I could access a java servlet using ajax and it didn't work.

In the script:

```
 var xmlhttp=new xmlHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.write=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/timer/timer, true);
     xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

and in my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //code
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("hi");
```

All I am trying to do here is write "hi".  What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you get any error on client side? May be in JS console

Comment: you have to flush and close the writer:

Comment: @Ilya no i don't believe so

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach can you explain that?  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Is this directly copy-pasted? You're missing the close quotation mark on the second parameter of `open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing to an `java.io.Writer` you have to execute `flush()` the internal Buffer to execute the operation on IO level. After all writing a stream should always get closed, to free the resources:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //code
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("hi");
    out.flush(); 
    out.close();
```

}

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29